# gamma correcting a sinusoidal grating [psychophysics]

Tags: vision, psychophysics, stimulation

I am developing a stimulation setting wherre I present a sinusoidal grating to a subject. Because of the monitor gamma expansion by a factor of 2.2, I need to gamma compress my sinusoidal grating by a factor of 1/2.2 = 0.45. I did it programatically.

The problem is the sinusoid is distorted by the gamma power-law non-linearities. Here is what I get:

[image].

A cross-section slice of that image is here:

[image].

However, because the monitor gamma expansion should cancel out my gamma compression. This is what I expected to obtain:

[image] ,

and the following cross-section:

[image]

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Do I need to programatically gamma correct my stimulus in order to compensate the monitor gamma? If so, why does the monitor gamma not restore my original undistorted sinusoid grating through cancelation?